# Find from file a, and extract file b and its whole parentheses

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have two files, what I want is to do is to use **file a** and search number in **file b** and print its whole parentheses including the searched line. I'm not sure, if it's what it's called.

File a:

```
300
302
303
```

File b:

```
    [300] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [301] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [302] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [303] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {
        "Person street address"
        },
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {
        "His job description"
        },
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
```

Expected output:

```
    [300] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [302] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [303] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {
        "Person street address"
        },
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {
        "His job description"
        },
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
```

Tried using awk, but can't get it working.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next} $1 in a && /\[$1\]/,/^\t\},/ {print}' a b > c
```

Thank you for your help..

Comment: I don't think you can use `$1` directly in a pattern. `/\[$1\]/` should probably look like `$0 ~ "\[" $1 "\]"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't have access to a parser for this particular format and your records really are as simple and regular as you show, this will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    vals["["$1"]"]
    next
}
rec == "" { key = $1 }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
/^[[:blank:]]*},$/ {
    if ( key in vals ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    key = rec = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file_a file_b
    [300] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [302] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your solution works perfectly on the example, however, i may have made it too simple, actually some of the record may looks like (i edited my question to include the new sample data format)

Sorry for trouble.. when i apply to actual data it only print until address..
Thank you..

Comment: Nevermind, already got it to work sir, i change to { rec = rec $0 ORS }
/^\t},$/ {

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sed` the following line could help you.

```shell
while read n; do sed -n -e "/^\[$n\]/,/^},$/p" b.txt; done < a.txt
```

Comment: seems like it print nothing, btw, i miss look  the b file actually got <tab>. i change my question slightly.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Below command and worked fine

command

```
for i in `cat filea`; do sed -n '/'$i'/,/^[[:space:]]\{4\}\},$/p' fileb; done
```

output

```
 [300] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [302] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {""},
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {"some job"},
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
    [303] = {
        name = "John",
        age = "12",
        address = {
        "Person street address"
        },
        job = "Marketing",
        job a = "some job",
        job b = {
        "His job description"
        },
        car = 0,
        salary = 0
    },
```